# What are the SPSS *.bin files?

Tags: space, disk, spss, bin

SPSS 19 keeps creating new files with BIN extensions in my user\AppData\Local\Temp folder.  Many of them are about 8gb in size, and they have started to crash my system.  What are they?  Can I delete them?  How can I prevent them from being created?

Thanks,
Marty

Answer (score 0):

I think these are cache files that SPSS creates during several procedures, notably during `SORT`.